# clearing the display in a javascript calculator after pressing "="

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm new to coding and I built a Javascript calculator, but I can't get the display to clear after Im done with one calculation. Instead, the result of the first calculation goes into the input for the second calculation. For eg if I do 3+5 it'll give me 8, but if I then press 4, the display says 84 which is why its a problem. I can clear the screen via the clear button but it gets tedious after every single calculation. Thank you.

```
//select all the buttons
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

//select the <input type="text" class+"display" disabled> element
const display = document.querySelector('.display');

//add eventListener to each button
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
button.addEventListener('click',calculate);
});

//calculate function
   function calculate(event) {
   //current clicked buttons value
   var clickedButtonValue = event.target.value;

   if(clickedButtonValue === '=') {

       //check if the display is not empty then only do the calculation
       if(display.value !== "") {

           //calculate and show the answer to display
           display.value = eval(display.value);
       }

       //if any key except "=" pressed again clear display
       button.addEventListener('click',clearDisplay);

   } else if (clickedButtonValue === 'C') {

       //clear everything on display
       display.value = "";

   } else {

       //otherwise concatenate it to the display
       display.value += clickedButtonValue;
   }
}

function clearDisplay(clickedButtonValue) {
    if(clickedButtonValue !== "=") {
        display.value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable that keeps track of the calculated state. If it has been calculated, clear the display and reset the state

```
var calculated = false;

function calculate( event ){
    var clickedButtonValue = event.target.value;

    if ( calculated ) {
        display.value = "";

        calculated = false;
    }

    if(clickedButtonValue === '=') {
        if(display.value !== "") {

            //calculate and show the answer to display
            display.value = eval(display.value);

            calculated = true;
        }
    }
    // the rest of your logic here
}
```